# What is FloatingMenuButton and why it is appearing on some of my apps?

Tags: android

It seems it is something for Samsung devices. I am not sure how to disable inside the app. It is appearing on some of my apps and I didn't add any code for it.

I figured out its name from logcat:

```
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$FloatingMenuButton
```

Here is my simple layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient_bg">
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
android:background="#98d08f"/>

    <FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/gallery_fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/my_awesome_toolbar"       >
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting as an answer for other people who would have same mysterious problem. When you do not declare minSdk for your app, this FloatingMenuButton appears on samsung devices. If you declare minSdk inside manifest, problem will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

If the application displaying the button has the permission to draw over other apps (like Facebook Messenger - the chat bubble), then there is nothing you can do

Comment: no it has not permission to draw over other apps. button shows up on my app's activities.